# Using click.CommandCollection drops group options

Tags: python, python-click

```
import click

@click.group()
@click.option('--username')
def cli1(username):
    click.echo(username)

@cli1.command()
def something():
    click.echo('howdy')

@click.group()
def cli2():
    pass

@cli2.command()
def somethingelse():
    click.echo('doody')

cli = click.CommandCollection(sources=[cli1, cli2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

I would expect that this would allow me to pass `--username` to `something`, but when I run this script:

```
python script.py something --username hi
```

I get:

> Error: no such option: --username

It seems like using the `CommandCollection` is breaking my options. Has anyone else dealt with this before? There is an open ticket in the click repo for this that hasn't been touched since 2015 and has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of new plumbing this can be done.

#### How??

You can inherit from `click.Group` and then pass the created class to `click.group()` like:

```
@click.group(cls=GroupWithCommandOptions)
```

In the new class, the options on the group can be applied to the command for parsing, and then during command invocation, the group function can be called with the appropriate options.

#### New Group Class:

```
import click

class GroupWithCommandOptions(click.Group):
    """ Allow application of options to group with multi command """

    def add_command(self, cmd, name=None):
        """ Hook the added command and put the group options on the command """
        click.Group.add_command(self, cmd, name=name)

        # add the group parameters to the command
        for param in self.params:
            cmd.params.append(param)

        # hook the command's invoke with our own
        cmd.invoke = self.build_command_invoke(cmd.invoke)
        self.invoke_without_command = True

    def build_command_invoke(self, original_invoke):

        def command_invoke(ctx):
            """ insert invocation of group function """

            # separate the group parameters
            ctx.obj = dict(_params=dict())
            for param in self.params:
                name = param.name
                ctx.obj['_params'][name] = ctx.params[name]
                del ctx.params[name]

            # call the group function with its parameters
            params = ctx.params
            ctx.params = ctx.obj['_params']
            self.invoke(ctx)
            ctx.params = params

            # now call (invoke) the original command
            original_invoke(ctx)

        return command_invoke
```

#### Test Code:

```
# Pass new group class to our group which needs options
@click.group(cls=GroupWithCommandOptions)
@click.option('--username')
def cli1(username):
    click.echo(username)


@cli1.command()
def something():
    click.echo('howdy')


@click.group()
def cli2():
    pass


@cli2.command()
def somethingelse():
    click.echo('doody')


cli = click.CommandCollection(sources=[cli1, cli2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli('something --username hi'.split())
```

#### Results:

```
hi
howdy
```